# Inaccessible due to its protection level when making a list inside loops

Tags: c#

```
public List<string> output = new List<string>();

List<string> newNumeralSystem(char number) {
    string Alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char[]a = new char[25];
    a = Alph.ToCharArray();
    int ac = Array.IndexOf(a,number);

    for(int x = 0; x > 25; x++)
    {
        int m = ac - x;

        if(m != 0)
        {
            //output[x] = string.Format(a[m] +"+"+ a[x]);
            output.Add(new string(){a[m] + "+" + a[x]});
        }
    }

    return output;      
}
```

I keep getting this

> error CS0122: `SpanHelpers.Add<T>(IntPtr, int)` is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: You haven't posted any code that shows `SpanHelpers.Add`. Where does the error occur?

Comment: I cant check it because I'm using online compiler

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you expect proper help.

Comment: That sort of information would be helpful in the question. What online compiler?

Comment: Compiler in app.codesignal.com

Comment: This code is not going to run for all sorts of reasons _"output.Add(new string(){a[m] + "+" + a[x]});"_ is not valid C# - maybe the compiler cannot get the correct override - try _"output.Add(a[m] + "+" + a[x]);"_

Comment: Once you get it compiling you will find the result is always an empty list - you should be checking for _"x < 25"_ in the for loop (though Alph.Length is better than 25 in both usages). The if statement needs to check _"m >= 0"_.